How to create C# OPC-Foundation Server OPC-UA?
I am trying to develop OPC-UA base servers with the gratid OPC-Foundation library ( latest update )
I am using C# and .net6.0.
After the various certificate problems I managed to create this working code.

CertificateIdentifier certificate = new CertificateIdentifier { SubjectName = "localhost" };
var applicationConfiguration = new ApplicationConfiguration
{
    ApplicationName = "server",
    SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration { TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList(),
                                                         ApplicationCertificate = certificate},
    ServerConfiguration = new ServerConfiguration(),
    TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas()
};


await applicationConfiguration.Validate(ApplicationType.Server);

var applicationInstance = new ApplicationInstance(applicationConfiguration);

// This call will check that the application instance certificate exists, and will create it if not
var result =
    await applicationInstance.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, CertificateFactory.DefaultKeySize);

var server = new StandardServer();
await applicationInstance.Start(server);

But how do I connect using an OPC-UA client? I am trying UA-Expert but it doesn't find anything on the local network.
